# Accessing ProgressBar in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have the following code that I am trying to figure out but I am completely stumped.  I am adding the progressbar into the listview, but I really don't know how to access each progressbar to update the progress values.

```
public ProgressBar LvAddProgB(ListView LV, int LVII, int LVColI, string lvName)
{
    Rectangle SizeR = default(Rectangle);
    ProgressBar ProgBar = new ProgressBar();

    SizeR = LV.Items[LVII].Bounds;
    SizeR.Width = LV.Columns[LVColI].Width;
    if (LVColI > 0)
    {
        SizeR.X = SizeR.X + LV.Columns[LVColI - 1].Width;
    }
    ProgBar.Parent = LV;
    ProgBar.Name = lvName;
    ProgBar.SetBounds(SizeR.X, SizeR.Y, SizeR.Width, SizeR.Height);
    ProgBar.Visible = true;
    ProgBar.Maximum = 1000;
    ProgBar.Step = 1;

    return ProgBar;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = "d.Name";
        item.SubItems.Add("                 ");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        LvAddProgB(listView1, x, 1, "Lview" + x.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `LVAddProgB` is returning a ProgressBar but you aren't doing anything with it. You need to store it into some type of collection then access it from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a key of some sort, you can fish it back out of the Controls collection to update.  Since each is displayed as if it was part of the ListView, it seems like there is some sort of linkage between the two. A key will also provide a way to link the item and related `ProgressBar`.

Assuming your `ListView` is `Details` view, just add a subitem at the end, **without** a related `ColumnHeader`.  The data will not show, but will still be related to the Item.  Use the same text as the `ProgressBar` name and it is easy to find.

My `ListView` has 3 columns: `{Item, Name, Completion}`, but the code will add a 4th subitem to store the key:

```
private void AddLVItem(string key, string name, int value)
{ 
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();

    lvi.SubItems[0].Text = name;
    lvi.SubItems.Add(value.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add(key);            // LV has 3 cols; this wont show
    lv.Items.Add(lvi);

    Rectangle r = lvi.SubItems[2].Bounds;
    pb.SetBounds(r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
    pb.Minimum = 1;
    pb.Maximum = 10;
    pb.Value = value;
    pb.Name = key;                   // use the key as the name
    lv.Controls.Add(pb);
}
```

Then, a method to update the Value and Progress bar for a given key:

```
private void UpdateItemValue(string key, int value)
{ 
    ListViewItem lvi;
    ProgressBar pb;

    // find the LVI based on the "key" in 
    lvi = lv.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.SubItems[3].Text == key);
    if (lvi != null)
        lvi.SubItems[1].Text = value.ToString();

    pb = lv.Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == key);
    if (pb != null)
        pb.Value = value;
}
```

usage:

```
// add some data
AddLVItem("A", "Ziggy", 1);
AddLVItem("B", "Zacky", 1);
AddLVItem("C", "Zoey", 1);
AddLVItem("D", "Zeke", 1);

// update the displayed value and progressbar using the key:
UpdateItemValue("A", 6);
UpdateItemValue("B", 5);
UpdateItemValue("C", 8);
UpdateItemValue("D", 2);
```

[image]

Comment: I am going to have to go with this answer because my issue was knowing how to access the progressbars and update then as needed.  You pretty much showed me how to do that with your code.  Thanks for the help and the example.

Comment: If the ListView cannot be edited, you could use Item Text instead of a key

Comment: It will not be edited, its just for downloading and displaying progress exactly like in your example.  I just don't need any fancy listview with tons of features. your response was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.columnHeader1 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.columnHeader2 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.columnHeader3 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // listView1
        // 
        this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnHeader1,
        this.columnHeader2,
        this.columnHeader3});
        this.listView1.GridLines = true;
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 64);
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 164);
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // columnHeader1
        // 
        this.columnHeader1.Width = 99;
        // 
        // columnHeader2
        // 
        this.columnHeader2.Width = 117;
        // 
        // columnHeader3
        // 
        this.columnHeader3.Width = 117;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(528, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar vScrollBar1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeader1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeader2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeader3;

    public ProgressBar LvAddProgB(ListView LV, int X, int Y, string lvName)
    {
        ProgressBar ProgBar = new ProgressBar();
        ProgBar.Parent = LV;
        ProgBar.Name = lvName;
        ProgBar.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        ProgBar.Visible = true;
        ProgBar.Maximum = 1000;
        ProgBar.Step = 1;

        return ProgBar;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = "d.Name";
            item.SubItems.Add("                 ");
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
            listView1.Controls.Add(LvAddProgB(listView1, item.Position.X + item.Bounds.Width, item.Position.Y, "Lview" + x.ToString()));
        }
    }
```